# Spring cloud gateway backend uri modification

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-gateway

Can someone please explain how spring-cloud-gateway routes the request ? Say I have following code

```
public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            //User registration service
            .route("register-user", routeSpec -> routeSpec
                    .path("/register")
                    .and()
                    .method(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .uri("http://localhost:8086/"))
}
```

Here can I change the URI, after this piece of code is executed(I mean after building the route in RouteLocatorBuilder) ? with help of any of the filter ? If so which object is holding route URL ? where do I need to modify the URL ? All I can find in the internet is rewriting the incoming request , none talks about modifying the backend URI. Any Supporting Documentation would help better. Thank you